# Does the train horn noise mean anything?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

Every now and then I hear a noise that seems to be pretty much random. The only way I can describe it is the sound of a train horn. If you've played this game, then you'd know what I mean.

This is the first Fallout game I've played, so I don't know if sounds usually mean anything. But I have played Skyrim, another Bethesda game, and in that game there were a ton of sounds that at first seemed to be meaningless that I later realised had a connection, like Nirnroots having their own eerie song.

Does the train horn sound mean anything or is it just random?

Comment: Are you playing with any mods? Ive gone through the story twice and can honestly say I have never heard a sound I would call a Train Horn...

Comment: Yeah, I've also played through this game a ton and have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: I'm playing without mods. IDK how else to describe it. Kind of like a deep wailing noise. I guess it's nothing since no one seems to know what I'm talking about. I'm kind of surprised you didn't recognise what I mean though, since like 90% of my playthrough has been me thinking "wtf why does that noise keep happening?" I don't play with radio on for reference.

Comment: Interesting. Can you relate it to something in the world, like entering combat? Could it be something in the ambient music track that you think sounds like it?

Comment: Perhaps you could get a recording of it? I dont remember this sound, either, and I played this game loyally when it first came out

Comment: I have to chime in that I just finished a play through a few weeks ago and don't know what sound you mean.

Comment: Could you perhaps be using the [Railway Rifle](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Railway_rifle)? I remember it mostly from Fallout 3, but quick googling confirms that it is in New Vegas. IIRC the weapon makes a train sound when you fire it. Also, **@CloseVoters, it is very clear what OP is asking.** If you feel content that this is unique to OPs game, a simple "there is no repetative railway sound in vanilla new vegas" answers the question.

Comment: @Timelord64 Your link confirms it *isn't* in New Vegas.

Comment: Your right, @Studoku. Read the excerpt instead of the body. It appears its only available with mods, which OP states they are not using.

Comment: @Timelord64 his edit was made via "improve edit" in the suggested edits queue. Minor edits made by 2k+ users are also perfectly acceptable; the problem is more with edits made by sub-2k users. (Granted this is more of an issue on, say, SO than here.) That's part of the reason why 2k+ users have no minimum character count.

Comment: @victoriah Does the sound play at the same time you get the 'Bad Karma' notification? (as suggested in an [answer by oaml yya](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/239125/4797))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Random noises are ambient sound files. You're most likely hearing a 'metal' one; the kind that like to play when you're near those giant power transmission towers. Try listening to the files in these directories:

`data\sound\fx\amb\~regions\metal`

`data\sound\fx\amb\~region\city\creaking`

Answer (score 8):

Are you perhaps talking about the [Bad Karma](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IfwA79JwS6Q) sound?

It's the only sound that I would make sense of sounding like a train horn.  Bad karma can only be obtained by doing "bad" things.

From the [wiki:](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Karma_(Fallout:_New_Vegas))

> Karma doesn't have as much of an effect on gameplay as in Fallout,
>   Fallout 2 and Fallout 3, since reputation has a more important place.
>
> However, it does still exist and if someone catches you performing an
>   action that causes negative Karma against their faction you will often
>   lose reputation with that faction; for example, stealing something
>   from The Silver Rush where a Van Graff can see you. They may also
>   become openly hostile despite your reputation with them not being
>   lowered enough for you to be considered hated where they will attack
>   you.

Comment: you are right, its most likely the bad karma sound.  It does kinda sound like a train now that I think about it.